# Intellij does not build JavaFX with libraries

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am developing a JavaFX application that has a lot of libs. If i run it inside intellij it works ok, but when i build the JavaFX application it only builds the .JAR of the project files, it doesn't even copy the libraries to the OUT folder.
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence below worked for me on a Mac with Idea 13.1, no guarantees it will work on anything else (it's all one big continuous process of button clicks):

```
File Menu | Project Structure | Artifacts | + Button |  
JavaFx Application | From module... | Choose Module | 
Output Layout Tab | + Button | Library Files | 
Choose Libraries |  JavaFX Tab | Choose an Application Class |
Make any changes needed |  Apply | OK | Build Menu | 
Build Artifacts | Choose your new artifact | Choose Build
```

Built artifact including any libraries will end up in your project `out/artifacts` directory.

If you want to make it so that others who don't use Idea could also build your project then you could investigate usage of a 3rd party JavaFX build tool, such as the [JavaFX Gradle plugin](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle) or the [Oracle JavaFX deployment toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/basic_deployment.htm).